# Testcontainers execInContainer not working with CockroachDB

Tags: testcontainers, cockroachdb

I'm using Testcontainers to start a CockroachDB instance with docker.
I need to enable support for temporary tables by setting the property `sql.defaults.experimental_temporary_tables.enabled` to true.

When the machine is running, I can do it with:

```
docker exec -it CockroachDBHibernate ./cockroach sql --insecure -e "SET CLUSTER SETTING sql.defaults.experimental_temporary_tables.enabled = 'true';"
```

But when I try to run the same command with Testcontainers:

```
container.execInContainer(
                    "./cockroach sql --insecure -e \"SET CLUSTER SETTING sql.defaults.experimental_temporary_tables.enabled = 'true';\"" );
```

I have the following error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "./cockroach sql --insecure -e \"SET CLUSTER SETTING sql.defaults.experimental_temporary_tables.enabled = 'true';\"": stat ./cockroach sql --insecure -e "SET CLUSTER SETTING sql.defaults.experimental_temporary_tables.enabled = 'true';": no such file or directory: unknown
```

Note that the error is visible via `Container.ExecResult#getStdout()`.
Exit code is 126

I'm using Testcontainers `1.15.2` and CockroachDB `v20.2.5`

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 container.execInContainer( "sh", "-c", "./cockroach sql --insecure -e \"SET CLUSTER SETTING sql.defaults.experimental_temporary_tables.enabled = 'true';\"" );
```